# Modify Recipients for a MAPI message

Tags: c++, visual-c++, com, atl, mapi

what i need to do is to backup recipients of MAPI message, and do some modification to the message (which may change the recipients also), after that i want to copy the backed up recipient back to the message again, here is the flow: 
message is the MAPI IMessage object
call message->GetRecipientTable, the result is LPMAPITABLE 
do changes to message
call message->ModifyRecipients, which takes LPADRLIST

my problem is that i want to take the result LPMAPITABLE and input that into ModifyRecipients, but it takes only LPADRLIST. is there a way to convert that? other than looping LPMAPITABLE and copying one by one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `IMAPITable::QueryRows`. Or `HrQueryAllRows` (which wraps `IMAPITable::SetColumns/Restrict/QueryRows` in a single call). `SRowSet` can be cast to `AdrList` - they have the same memory layout.

Comment: by the way. i used IMAPITable::QueryRows, however, i am not able to use HrQueryAllRows at all in my code, i am not able to use any of the methods starting Hr, i included mapi.h, but the linker always complaining: Error 1 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _HrQueryAllRows@24, should i include a dll or something to make it work?

Comment: Load HrQueryAllRows dynamically. Look at the MFCMAPI source code for an example on how to load the MAPI system and its functions.